# WinForms: Show form modal over other application's main window

Tags: c#, winforms, modal-dialog

Is it possible to show a WinForms modal form over another process's main window?

For example my WinForms application consists of one form which is modal over another process's main window with PID x.

Comment: Tried 'TopMost=true' property?

Comment: Not exactly what I want but would work in some situations...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can show it as a dialog, like so:

```
Form1 frm = new Form1();
frm.ShowDialog(this);
frm.Dispose();
```

You pass the current `IWin32Window` or `form` you want to be the owner, so if you're calling it from say a button click on the parent form, just pass through `this`.

You want to be able to get the `IWin32Window` for another process, which is possible, but I don't know if showing a form as a modal over that is.

```
var proc = Process.GetProcesses().Where(x => x.ProcessName == "notepad").First();
IWin32Window w = Control.FromHandle(proc.MainWindowHandle);

using (Form1 frm = new Form1())
{
    frm.ShowDialog(w);
}
```

This is how it would work, if it was possible, however, it doesn't seem to work for me.

This link may shed a bit more information on the subject: [How can I make a child process window to appear modal in my process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613513/how-can-i-make-a-child-process-window-to-appear-modal-in-my-process)

Comment: `form.ShowDialog()` opens it in another process?

Comment: For example a second application which is running on the system. Not a modal form in the same application

Comment: This works for me, thanks. 
How can I reach that the modal dialog is created out of the main routine without having another normal non modal main form created?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question?

Comment: I want to create a WinForms application which just shows a modal dialog over another application like you described above. For now I create a hidden main form which is supplied to the Application.Run(). This main form raises the modal dialog. So how can I create a modal form out of the main method?

Comment: Yes this works, not as complicated as I thought it needs to be ;-)